# Cookie de autorización sin expiración solo para una página web

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, cookies

¿Existe la posibilidad de que una página web de un proyecto ASP.NET pueda usar una Cookie de autenticación que no expire nunca (o que expire cuando se cierre el navegador), pero que no actualice la Cookie principal de autenticación que se utiliza para otras páginas web del mismo proyecto?

Mi problema está relacionado a que tengo un proyecto ASP.NET que utiliza Cookies para almacenar la información de autenticación del usuario, la cual está programada para que expire tras 20 minutos. El problema es que debemos crear una página web para este mismo proyecto que requiere leer esta Cookie de autenticación (para saber qué usuario es), pero esta no debe refrescar el vencimiento de la Cookie. Dicho de esta manera, esta nueva única página se debe mantener disponible aún si el usuario no interactúa con esta, pero las demás si se deben impedir su acceso si no existe actividad por parte del usuario.

Comment: ¿Por qué iria a actualizarse el vencimiento de la cookie si solo van a leer el valor en ella? Deberías mostrarnos algo de contexto...

Comment: Esto se debe a que el proyecto web está configurado para que se refresque el vencimiento de esta de manera automática si el usuario presenta actividad (a través de la propiedad slidingExpiration)